# Can we call the pipeline in parallel and have multiple instances running?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a scenario where I have to execute a pipeline from different pipelines to log the validations.

So I'm planning to have a single pipeline for all the validations (like counts, duplicates, count drops etc..) and this pipeline should be trigger when a particular table execution completes.

for example: There are two pipelines P1 & P2 which both invokes this validation pipeline upon completion. so there is a chance that this validation pipeline may trigger twice at same time.

can we run a pipeline like this? is there any lock will applied automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse a pipeline which acts as generic pipeline in other pipelines and call them parallelly and there is no lock aspect.
Just that make sure the generic pipeline is allowed parallel executions else it would be in queue

[image]